# Why KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES doesn't work?

Tags: android, kill-process

In the AndroidManifest.xml, I have this permission:

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

But still I am getting the error message as:

```
Permission Denial: killBackgroundProcesses() from ... requires android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
```

This method was invoked from:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(RunningAppProcessInfo runningProcess : runningProcesses) {
        if(runningProcess.processName.equals("com.example.nihao")) {
            Log.v("Hello", "kill process "+runningProcess.pid);
            //android.os.Process.killProcess(runningProcess.pid);
            am.killBackgroundProcesses("com.example.nihao");
        }
    }
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a typo, `user-permission` should be `uses-permission`.